# Is there a function for getting the parent state value when in a compounded state (hierarchical state) in xState?

Tags: state-machine, xstate, state-machine-workflow, xstate-react

I used the parent states name for some utility purposes, the problem is when trying to retrieve it from a child state as it returns an object with the parents state value as the object key.

Below is the code to get the value when in the parent state:

```
console.log(this.state.value);
// "start_application"
```

This returns a string value.

When in a child state it returns the following:

```
console.log(this.state.value);
//  {
//    "customer_data": "no_data"
//  }
```

There are hacks to get the name, like checking if it is an object and then retrieving the object key value but this is awfully hacky (not in a good way :P).

Is there a better way of doing this or am I approaching it completely wrong?

Thanks in advance.